# Generating an empty tilemap in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create a TD game where the map is tilemap that generated in runtime.
for the moment I am trying to create the tilemap with empty tile just for the start and after that, I will use the A-star algorithm to make the path.
currently, I have this function written below.
Everything is working and I can see the grid and tilemap in the editor when the gamestart  but the tiles are not there...

```cs
   void initTilemap(){
        GameObject grid = new GameObject("Grid");
        GameObject tilemap = new GameObject("Tilemap");
        grid.AddComponent<Grid>();
        tilemap.AddComponent<Tilemap>();
        tilemap.transform.SetParent(grid.transform);
        collidableMap = tilemap.GetComponent<Tilemap>();
        collidableMap.ClearAllTiles(); 
        Tile tile = (Tile) Resources.Load("Tile/grass");
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
            {
            for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
            {
                Vector3Int p = new Vector3Int(x,y,0);

                // GameObject tile = new GameObject("TileBase");
                collidableMap.SetTile(p, tile);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to call [RefreshAllTiles()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tilemaps.Tilemap.RefreshAllTiles.html) on the TileMap after you make modifications in code.

Answer (score 0):

solved it by adding TilemapRenderer Component